# Is my solution to repeating HTML code clunky?

Tags: php, html

Say I have some HTML I want to use on multiple pages (ie: a nav that appears at the top of every page) and don't want to write it/copy and paste it for every page. What is the best way to abstract that code so I don't repeat myself? My current solution is to make all my pages php files and just write the HTML in there. This way, I can have a dedicated 'nav.php' file that I just insert into the pages where necessary, for example, by going:

```
<?php include 'nav.php';?>
```

I feel this is a lot of mucking around. Some were saying that using the HTML `<template>` tag was an option too?

If there's a better way, would appreciate some insight.

Comment: Yes, you can have a separate PHP file for navigation bar and you can include that file in your pages.

Comment: If you are okay to use some libraries, you can explore React.js and see how to achieve this kind of behavior (it's possible for sure).

Comment: @kiner_shah ok thanks. Is using the HTML <template> tag an option?

Comment: You've just reinvented templating in PHP

Comment: ***You can use the <template> tag if you have some HTML code you want to use over and over again, but not until you ask for it.*** https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_template.asp - I don't think so you can achieve the effect you want with this tag (I maybe wrong though).

Answer (score 1):

Super basic structure for most (all?) pages.

```
<?php

  // php code that is common across all pages.
  // Would include functions and classes.
  require_once('php/common.php');

  // Page logic and checking. Basically, what is happening
  // on this page that is dynamically constructed.
  $page = new Page();
  $title = $page->getTitle();
  $html = $page->getHtml();

  // 'Header' content, includes things like a navbar
  require_once('php/header.php');

  // page content (HTML) unique to this page
  echo $html;

  // 'Footer' content, include html common to all pages.
  require_once('php/footer.php');

?>
```

Comment: ok makes sense, thank you kindly sir